# angular 6 - problem with 3d touch on newest ios

Tags: ios, angular

I have problem with 3d touch in my angular 6 app. When browsing site on iphone 6 and newer (with newest ios), simple click is not recognized as click. You have to press screen a while in order to click something. On other mobile systems clicks work fine. I think this is related with 3d touch.

I'm using `(click)="DoAction()"` for handling clicks.

Is 3dtouch should be handled separately?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this library in your app and it works fine: 
https://pressurejs.com/

Comment: Can this libarary be used in angular 6 (we are using only typescript)? I don't want add js libararies unless this is only option. Since this is another layer for interactions - how this affects performance?

Comment: I think it will not make a big demerit to the performance of the app or you can use the Rxjs to handle the 3d touch by handle the touchstart , touchend events and use a directive to handle this.